# Can't build iOS/iPhone app as anything other than i386

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, compilation

I am completely new to the iOS/iPhone/XCode world, so if you guess is between something rather complex and something so simple that *everyone* should know, I'd go with the simple answer.  :-)

Okay, so I have inherited an iPhone project that we had outsourced to another company. My only objective right now is to be able to build the dang thing. I set up XCode 4.2 and installed the proper SDKs. I loaded up the project and everything seems good to this point. However, when I build, I get errors from what I believe to be the linking stage of the build. I'm not entirely sure because the statuses change quickly when building. The error I get is the following:

[image: Error from XCode build]

From what I have been able to find online, it seems that one of the libraries I am using was not compiled for the i386 platform. To start, this doesn't make sense to me because the libraries that I am using (where these errors are coming from) are currently included as sub-projects and produce **.a** files which I thought were arch-independent (am I wrong here??). Also, I can't find anywhere in the project where I've instructed XCode to build to an i386 architecture. This is what I've done so far:

- Made sure that the file in which these errors arose was included into the "Compile Sources" section of the Build Phase tab (the .m file)
- Set my architectures to **armv6** and **armv7** and set the **Build Active Architecture Only** to *no*. (See images below)

**Main Project Config**
[image: main project build configuration]

**Sub-Project Config**
[image: sub project config]

Event when I build using the release configuration, I still get this error and I'm not sure why. Everything that I am looking at in my build config seems to indicate that I should be building everything in an *arm* architecture.

Comment: static libraries CAN be architecture independent if the creator made them universal (using lipo). In most cases, developers do not do that (for reasons that are beyond my understanding), hence you will have to manually link the "right" library version depending on your current architecture.

Comment: i386 is for the simulator, and .a files are not platform independent, they are unix style static libs....like .lib on windows if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @borrrden, I believe .a files are object code, which means it's platform (processor) dependent.

Comment: At any rate, the libraries I am using are included as sub-projects and everything seems as if it should build to an *arm* architecture (see my build configs above). So I'm still not sure why I get this error at all.

Comment: are you trying to run on an actual device?

Comment: Anything really. I've tried to do an app-store (release) build and an emulator build. Just trying to get *something* to work...lol.

Comment: @borrrden your assumption is almost correct. iOS libraries can be multi platform (joined using LIPO) as drafted in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting errors because you messed with the architecture settings. You should not fix those towards ARM code but allow i386 as well.

Right now, one of more of your (sub)-projects build ARM code only, resulting into a linker error once you try to build a simulator version. That is happening because your Architecture settings are not as they should be.

Note your setting for ***Any iOS SDK***, that one is incorrect as it builds only ARM code. Remove those settings entirely by using the backspace key on your keyboard after selecting that specific setting (single-click).

And this is how it should be:
[image]

`$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` resolves to `ARMV7` when building device specific code and `i386` when building simulator specific code. Including `ARMV6` code as per my screenshot is only needed if you plan to serve the results to older iOS devices (iPhone 3G and below).

Once those settings are **active in all (sub)-projects**, everything should work smoothly.

For creating a universal library out of a project, useful if you plan to distribute a static library to other developers, use `LIPO`.

Example:

```
lipo input_library_1.a input_library_2.a -create -ouput output_library.a
```

Lets say input_library_1 was `i386` specific (simulator) and input_library_2 was `ARM` specific (device), this will join them into a universal version usable for both simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have been trying to link to static library built for devices(armv6 or armv7). When your building for the simulator the architecture will be i386. So you getting all these nasty linking errors. Solution is to include the library compiled for simulator as well in your project.